# Points not appearing on faces correctly

Tags: faces, geometry-nodes

[image]

I have applied scale, tried recalculating normals, nothing worked

Comment: It might help those who help to Edit your question and write one sentence about what you want to achieve with instancing.  Is it that not all faces are used?  Or how it compares with the Instancing that is Object instead of GeoNode.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to offset the leaves, you should do it before instancing on points, not after.